# Wordpress: How to add Attribute to body

Tags: wordpress, scrollspy, affix

I want to add [Scrollspy](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_scrollspy_affix&stacked=h) support to the nav-menu, for that I have to add extra attributes `data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar"` to the `body` tag.

Can I do that pragmatically without touching theme files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to:-
Edit `header.php` And add those attributes to the body.

Alternative (without editing theme files) way would be to create a plugin which adds a js that adds those attributes to body.
Something like this:-

```
$("body").attr( { data-spy:"scroll", data-target:".navbar" } );
```

**EDIT**
After viewing Sevi's answers.
The most suitable way is

```
function wp_body_classes( $classes )
{
    $classes[] = '" spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar';

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class','wp_body_classes', 999 );
```

Comment: The WordPress `body_class` filter method is not working for adding data attributes.

Comment: body_class filter wont work if your theme does not uses it

Comment: It's not working at all! The attributes are added inside the class attribute in the form of plain text. The answer of Mat below is the actual answer to this question.

Comment: This answer is not working 2022, @tousif what do you mean if "your theme does not uses it?" can you please elaborate? or add any code on how can we add `body_class` filter?

Comment: It means your body tag does to have <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
Details here:-
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/

Answer (score 6):

Well, I found solution to my question:

```
function wp_body_classes( $classes )
{
    $classes[] = '" spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar';

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class','wp_body_classes', 999 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this can't be done without editing the theme files. You could try the jQuery method that tousif has mentioned above but I doubt it will work as it will most likely fire after ScrollSpy has been loaded.

Best way to do this is to edit your '`header.php`' file and add the attributes to the `<body>` tag. You shouldn't edit the theme itself though, use a child theme - https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes